# Inflate drawable out of the layout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-imageview, android-custom-view

I have a layout defining item of listview. I need to have it as follows:

[image]

I need that red rectangle (ImageView) to overlays over two LinearLayouts (see the image I've uploaded).

My current list item layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:paddingLeft="15dip"
    android:paddingRight="15dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/item_rounded"
        android:padding="15dip" >
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Item 1"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/background"
        android:paddingLeft="15dip"
        android:paddingRight="15dip" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/item_rounded"
            android:padding="15dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Item 1"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#FF0000" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try below code

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffeecc"
    android:paddingLeft="15dip"
    android:paddingRight="15dip" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/item_rounded"
        android:padding="15dip" >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Item 1"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```